# Find element in array using regex match without iterating over array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of elements

```
["page=4", "sortOrder=asc", "datePosted=all-time"]
```

Using javascript or jquery I want to find the index of the element which begins  `"sortOrder="` . I will not know the full string of this element at compile time, just the `"sortOrder="` part.

I'm assuming that this can be done without the need to iterate over the array and perform `item.match("sortOrder=")`, but maybe I am wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You do need to iterate over the array at some point. Whether it's abstracted by a framework or not, it still needs to happen.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to get the **value** inside an array that matches a specific regex:

...to get the **value** of the first match only, you can use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=control)

```
const array = ["page=4", "sortOrder=asc", "datePosted=all-time", "sortOrder=desc"];
const match = array.find(value => /^sortOrder=/.test(value));
// match = "sortOrder=asc"
```

...to get an **array** of all match results, you can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control)

```
const array = ["page=4", "sortOrder=asc", "datePosted=all-time", "sortOrder=desc"];
const matches = array.filter(value => /^sortOrder=/.test(value));
// matches = ['sortOrder=asc', 'sortOrder=desc'];
```

...to get the **index** of the first match, you can use [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?v=control)

```
const array = ["page=4", "sortOrder=asc", "datePosted=all-time", "sortOrder=desc"];
const index = array.findIndex(value => /^sortOrder=/.test(value));
// index = 1;
```

If you are not using ES6, here's [the code in ES5](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=const%20array%20%3D%20%5B%22page%3D4%22%2C%20%22sortOrder%3Dasc%22%2C%20%22datePosted%3Dall-time%22%2C%20%22sortOrder%3Ddesc%22%5D%3B%0Aconst%20match%20%3D%20array.find(value%20%3D%3E%20%2F%5EsortOrder%3D%2F.test(value))%3B%0A%2F%2F%20match%20%3D%20%22sortOrder%3Dasc%22).

Answer (score 5):

Sadly there's no partial match in indexOf... Try this and see if it helps:

```
Array.prototype.MatchInArray = function (value) {

    var i;

    for (i=0; i < this.length; i++) {

        if (this[i].match(value)) {

           return i;

       }

   }

   return -1;

};
```

Comment: consider returning the index (`i`) or `-1` (if not found), since this provides a bit more information and is on par with `Array.indexOf`

Comment: Done. Thanks @zamnuts!.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find an item in an array, you'll have to iterate over it. If you array is in a known order (eg: it is sorted alphabetically), then there are some efficiencies you could build in to the search algorithm (eg: binary tree search), however unless you have thousands of items in the array it's hardly going to be worth it. In your case, just loop over the array checking each item against your regex and return when you find a match.

Answer (score 1):

New [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) function from ES6 makes it possible to do what you want, use regex and not iterate over array.

Here you have a sample of how it can be done: https://jsbin.com/qemeseyeme/edit?js,console

Full code sample:

```
const arr = ["page=4", "sortOrder=asc", "datePosted=all-time"];
const str = "sortOrder";

function isStringInArray(str, arr) {

  if (arr.findIndex(_strCheck) === -1) return false;

  return true;

  function _strCheck(el) {

    return el.match(str);
  }
}

console.log(isStringInArray(str, arr));
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you're wrong - you need to iterate. In ES5 there's a new method to find array positions - `Array.indexOf` but there's no support for this in older browsers and it needs an exact match not partial.

Comment: Ah okay yes, I saw `Array.IndexOf` and wondered if there was anything similar but with a partial match. Shame that there isn't.